# How to grant a user to run "sudo sh" without having to typing password?

Tags: linux, sudo

I want to grant it to a specific user A only, how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put:

```
A ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

in `/etc/sudoers`.  If you only want to allow `sh`, change the second `ALL` to `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Is `:` after `NOPASSWD` necessary or typo?

Comment: It is necessary

Answer (score 8):

Put this in the sudoers:

username  ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/sh

And for the sake of teaching a man how to fish, this info is found in the man file for sudo. Just type in 'man sudo' and you'll get all the info you need.